# Want to create a thumbnail(25,25) of an Image of size (181,256) using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to create thumbnail(25,25) of an image whose size is 181 x 256. But when i run the code i get the output image of (17,25) thumbnail image . Why am i not getting a image of 25 x 25 height and width?

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
size=25,25
im=array(Image.open('D:/1.png'))
im.thumbnail(size)
im.save("Thumbnail.png","PNG")
print im.shape
```

Comment: Because the thumbnail function preserves the aspect ratio. Try the resize method.

Comment: @M4rtini -Suppose i want to create a thumbnail of 25  x 25 cant i create using thumbnail function in python. How can i create a thumbnail image of 25 x 25 from an original image 181 x 256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
size=25,25
im=(Image.open('...'))
im = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save("Thumbnail.png","PNG")
imgArr = array(im)
print imgArr.shape
```